# How to access localStorage in node.js?

Tags: node.js, local-storage

I tried searching the web for a node module that can access the client's localStorage but wasn't able to find anything. Anyone know of one?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? `localStorage` is an HTML 5 API and only available on browsers. Node.js would use the file system or a database for persistence.

Comment: I have a scenario where a user lands on a page and has already been supplied a token value in localStorage from another page on the same domain. However that part of the site wasn't running node, and now I'm in node and need the token value. Not the ideal setup.

Comment: Looks like the options are switch from localStorage to cookies or make an ajax request.

Comment: A cookie will go to the server with the request, yes. If it is cookie sized data, a state token, or a small set of preferences, it might be easier to share state between server applications. The advantage is that the cookie data arrives to Node.js before anything is served, so you can pivot on it. On the other hand, nn AJAX end point is awfully easy to write in Node.js. You app is probably already JavaScript heavy if you're using `localStorage`.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://github.com/coolaj86/node-localStorage

Comment: I just created a library for this, check it out: https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist

Comment: @user1766449 this looks pretty sweet; I will definitely try this out!

Comment: If you're looking for something more powerful than local storage via Node.js. Check out PouchDB node edition https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-node

Comment: This looks like it's asking for an external library. Is there an exception for Node or am I justified in my thinking?

Answer (score 54):

You can use :

`node-localstorage` npm module to use `localStorage` at the [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) server side.

```
var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage,
localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
```

Comment: what is `'./scratch'`?

Comment: It doesn't work in the client browser. localstorage in the browser is empty even if a value is set.

Comment: @kittu, `./scratch` is the file that is used as the data store for `localStorage`. It can be any file like: `/tmp/node-${process.pid}-localStorage`. Ref: https://github.com/lmaccherone/node-localstorage/blob/758079000ce4edc21648102c8588a9eebb0d34cf/LocalStorage.coffee#L53

Comment: @shrawan_lakhe, @TuanNguyen; It is not meant to work client-side. It is a server-side "localStorage" implementation. For client-side storage, use `window.localStorage`.

Comment: It's weird that this answer gets upvotes while a similar answer gets a -1... they are both assuming localstorage is a sever-side issue

Comment: Worth noting: If your node app is running in a container or virtualization like docker or aws ecs then your localStorage would die with restarts of the container because the virtual ./scratch directory would be lost.

Comment: This isn't the solution. The data is stored on the server, and the state is visible to other users who visit the same website or use the same application. Instead, you could use the Fetch API with a post request.

Comment: @EdisonPebojot _"use the Fetch API with a post request."_ -- This is not necessarily applicable. For example, I was looking for this information for a desktop NodeJS app, which has nothing to do with requests, or a web server even. I just wanted a simple kvp store resembling localStorage, which this answer solves just fine.

Answer (score 38):

If you mean html 5 localStorage, there's no such a thing since node.js is a server-side technology. Html 5 localStorage is a client side feature supported

Comment: There are plenty of modules that bring the DOM to the server-side, webkit to the server-side, so I was curious if someone had brought localStorage to the server-side.

Comment: Having locastorage on server is not a need. localStorage is needed for browsers as a persistence layer, a way to store data. This is available to server side technologies as memory, filesystem, database, redis etc.

However some javascript modules may emulate it for several other purposes (unit testing for example)

Answer (score 13):

When the page loads, send a post that queries the contents of the client's localStorage.

Comment: When the page loads, the browser already takes control, and we can read localStorage via js, you mean to say when the page loads, send a post with the localstorage content back to server

Answer (score 12):

Found this [`store`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/store)

```
// Store current user 
store.set('user', { name:'Marcus' })

// Get current user 
store.get('user')

// Remove current user 
store.remove('user')

// Clear all keys 
store.clearAll()

// Loop over all stored values 
store.each(function(value, key) {
    console.log(key, '==', value)
})
```

Comment: so on the back end i can set the localStorage and on front end i am able to see the name in console.log(localStorage.getItem("user")) ?

Answer (score 3):

For Node.js you can use [HandyStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handy-storage), a fast and small npm package which behaves data like a `state`
Here's an example:

```
const HandyStorage = require('handy-storage');

const storage = new HandyStorage('./store.json');

storage.setState({
    name: 'Alireza',
    lastname: 'Sh',
    friends: [
        'Jane',
        'John'
    ],
    visited: storage.state.visited || 0
})

storage.setState({
    visited: storage.state.visited + 1
})
```

It automatically changes the JSON file, just give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

LocalStorage is never accessible by the server. Ever. It would be a huge security issue.

If you need to send it to a server, then you have to have a client-side JS script which retrieves it, and then sends it to the server as part of an Ajax or POST request.

Cookies work well for when you need to pass small amounts of data regularly between server and client.

Databases on your server are best if you need to store data long-term.

Answer (score -1):

In the JS file you write this:

```js
const LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage,
  localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
```

Also you need:
open new Terminal press Control + C (don't worry it's for clear not for copy) and type you'r file.js (for ex: server.js) and than type this:      **npm i node-localstorage** (now you all set).

Answer (score -2):

Well, I think some explanations are in handy, first of all, node JS and V8 are two different things and runs on different places. Browsers uses the v8 engine to run JS, node JS runs on servers and is v8 based, but it doesn't have everything that the browser does (like the window object). So you can't access the browser local storage from your server because it's running somewhere (browsers runs on the user machine) else, I think that you want a lib that works like local storage but in your node js serve, for that we have store -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/store.

Answer (score -4):

I'm From 2022 and yet there is no way we can instantly get the browser's localStorage without using fetch or ajax to communicate to the server but if you use react or veu for instance they can access it. Because they are frontend base libraries and frameworks

Answer (score -5):

We can not save to localStorage on Node.js.

Comment: You can post this as comment, If you have a detail explanation which can help people in future then you can elaborate it and post it as answer :)

Comment: @SameerKhan he doesn't have enough reputation for comments