# How to set values in local storage of the browser using node js express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, local-storage

Till now, I was using cookies to save some preferences, for my websites. But with time, this has gone very big, and now it is exceeding the limit of 4096 chars.

So I have to find an alternate way of storing the data. Here I find, using local-storage can serve my purpose. But I couldn't find any example, how I can save some value in local storage of the browser from node js. Previously I used to send the cookie value with response, to save the cookie, can we do something similar for local storage.

I see some of the npm modules like node-localstorage etc. , but not sure, how I can save the data to the browser.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage 
use this

Comment: @Dherya I do not find any example or documentation to use this module with node js. DO you have any pointer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving into local storage with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182573/saving-into-local-storage-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

I would at first suggest using some kind of persistent data handler. Maybe a database on the server, or if you want to avoid server-handling, maybe you could use something like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) to handle your persistent data.

There is probably a ton of npm modules to save to local storage, but I guess it depends on what you're using it for, but maybe [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/store) can help? Otherwise if you're using the cookie to send information between different requests, maybe you could use query-strings on your requests instead?

So instead of saving preferences to a cookie, you send a querystring with the preferences on each request using

[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) & [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: I want to directly save some data from my server to the browser's local storage.. I tried using "store" npm module, but that doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Hmm, if the npm-modules doesn't work(haven't tried any before), can't you just send the preferences via websockets to the client, and save the local storage from the client?