# Access the browers local storage in Server Side Rendering in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Can anyone tell the best way how can we access the browsers local storage in Server Side Rendering in Angular 2? I found out a stackoverflow related to this : [localStorage is not defined (Angular Universal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085632/localstorage-is-not-defined-angular-universal) . But i didn't get the concept of providers used in it. Can anyone explain in brief what is the exact meaning of those providers used in main.browser.ts and main.node.ts?

Also i found a module angular-2-localstorage. So which is the best approach to access the local storage in Server side?

Comment: HTML5 local storage? You can't. It's a client-side feature.

Comment: So how to access local storage at server side? Because in server side rendering our first request goes to server and the rendered HTML gets rendered and returned, so how can server can access local storage there.In my case i have been storing token in local storage.So how can we access that token from server side?

Comment: @zurfyx that's the point of the question....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access localStorage in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358100/how-to-access-localstorage-in-node-js)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @Shailajashah

Comment: As I can see things there is no way for the server to have access to any data that is in the localStorage. In case there is data you need to get from the client when rendering in the server I guess you'll need to use cookies instead. The browser automatically attahces the cookies to any request to the server based on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do it would be to inject the `PLATFORM_ID` token into the constructor. The `PLATFORM_ID` is token that indicates an opaque platform id. Since `localStorage` is on the DOM, you can utilize a call to `isPlatformBrowser()` or `isPlatformServer()` to check if the `PLATFORM_ID` is on the browser or on the server. If the `PLATFORM_ID` is on the browser, then the DOM can be accessed, for example:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID };
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
....
@Component({

  export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object){}
  
    ngOnInit() {

      if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
        //do something
      }

    }
  }
)}
```

**Links**

[Accessing the DOM in Angular Universal](https://dafabulousteach.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/accessing-the-dom-in-angular-universal/)

[Local Storage in Angular Universal](https://github.com/ranavc32/AngularUniversal-localStorage/blob/master/src/app/home/home-page/home-page.component.ts)