# Is there any way of getting item from localstorage inside gatsby-node.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I want to get an item from **localstorage** inside **gatsby-node.js**
I tried like this :

```
exports.onCreateNode = async function({ node, actions }) {
  const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions

  // here i used for localstorage item
  console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("token"))


  createNodeField({
    node,
    name: `happiness`,
    value: `is sweet graphql queries`,
  })
}
```

And got error like this :

```
"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the onCreateNode lifecycle:

localStorage is not defined

  19 | exports.onCreateNode = async function({ node, actions }) {
  20 |   const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions
> 21 |   console.log(localStorage.getItem("token"))
     |               ^
  22 |   createNodeField({
  23 |     node,
  24 |     name: `happiness`,
```

**N.B.** I have set data **"token"** in my localstorage

Comment: Your function runs on a server and does not have access to a browser-based `localStorage` implementation. I suggest you use cookies instead.

Comment: Have a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358100/how-to-access-localstorage-in-node-js

Comment: can i get data using cookies in gatsby-node.js file? @its_tayo

Comment: Yes you should get, cookies work both server-side and client-side.