# storage.setItem is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const express = require("express");
const storage = require("node-persist");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.post("/addtask",async(req,res)=>{
    const {id,task}=req.body;
    try{
        const res = await storage.setItem(id,task);
        res.status(201).send("task added");
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(501).send({message:"some error occured",error});
        console.log(error);
    }
});
app.listen(5000);
```

My request body is:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "task": "go shop"
}
```

```
TypeError: storage.setItem is not a function
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\server.js:10:35
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module     6\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at cors (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\module 6\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:224:17
```

In this node.js code I am trying to post tasks in postman but I am getting error saying that storage.setItem is not a function. Why am I getting this error? Please help me to solve this.

Why am I getting this error which is saying storage.setItem is not a function.Please tell me where I have done the mistake?

Comment: where is `storage.init`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358100/how-to-access-localstorage-in-node-js are you trying to use localStorage API? apparently that is a browser API, not in node out of the box. the linked question includes a link to a library which replicates this API in node.js

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist upvote on "where is storage.init" comment are tee eff em

Comment: The OP's code already shows the use of the node-persist library to replicate local storage in nodejs.  So, this doesn't appear to be a question about browser vs. nodejs, but rather a question about why the node-persist library isn't working for them.

Comment: To clarify an earlier comment.  The code you show in this question does not show a call to `storage.init()` with at least an appropriate `dir` specified.